Using classical $g^{(1)}$ to calculate quantum $g^{(1)}$
Imagine a free space optical switch with several inputs and outputs. My question is:  can we use the first order cross correlation between the complex amplitudes of two classical beams of light at the output ports A and B (which were identical beams of light that entered at input ports A and B) to calculate the visibility/spatio-temporal overlap of two single photons $P_a$ and $P_b$ that entered and were initially identical at input ports A and B and exited the switch at output ports A and B.
The idea is to calculate how similar the beams of light/photons at the output ports are to each other. This is to understand how the switch has differently affected the beams/photons given that they were initially identical (at the input ports.) If the switch affects the input beams at A and B identically (or not at all), then we expect the first order crosscorrelation at A and B to be 1. If it affects the photons identically (or not at all) we expect the visibility to be 1 at A and B.
More details below:
Say we describe the state of $P_a$ and $P_b$ after they exited the switch as e.g:
$$ |P_i\rangle = \int_{0}^{\infty}dt \phi_i(t)a_i^{\dagger}(t)|0\rangle $$
where $\phi_i(t)$ describes the photon waveform. Then we find that
$$v=g_{HOM}^{(1)}[0]=\frac{\iint \langle P_a| a_a^{\dagger} a_b^{}|P_b\rangle dtdt'}{(\int \langle P_a|a_a^{\dagger}a_a^{}|P_a\rangle dt) (\int \langle P_b|a_a^{\dagger}a_a^{}|P_b\rangle dt)}$$ (eq 59 and 60 from Trivedi et al 2019) where the creation/destruction operators represent the action of photo-detectors.
Simplifying, we get:
$$ v=g_{HOM}^{(1)}[0]=\frac{\iint \phi_{a}^{*}(t)\phi_b(t') dtdt'}{(\int \phi_{a}^{*}(t)\phi_a(t) dt) (\int \phi_{b}^{*}(t)\phi_b(t)dt)}. $$
Therefore we see that visibility is equal to $g^{(1)}$ which is related to the similarity of the waveforms $\phi_a(t)$ and $\phi_b(t)$ of our photons $P_a$ and $P_b$. We can also see similar/related expressions relating the waveforms to $g^{(1)}$ in eq 64-67 of Trivedi et al 2019.
In classical optics, the first order correlation function is defined as:
$$g^{(1)}(r_1, t_1;r_2, t_2) = \frac{<E_a^{*}(r_1, t_1)E_b(r_2, t_2)>}{[<E_a^{*}(r_1, t_1)E_a(r_1, t_1)><E_b^{*}(r_2, t_2)E_b(r_2, t_2)>]^{1/2}}$$ (eq 3.4.14 Loudon 2000 The Quantum Theory of Light).
Averaging over the same points in space-time we get:
$$g^{(1)}(r,t) = \frac{\iint E_a^{*}(r, t)E_b(r, t)dr dt}{[( \iint E_a^{*}(r, t)E_a(r, t)dr dt) (\iint E_b^{*}(r, t)E_b(r, t)dr dt)]^{1/2}}$$
We clearly see that classical and quantum $g^{(1)}$ have the same form. The quantum $g^{(1)}$ can also be written in terms of the electric field operator (see eq 4.12.4 Loudon 2000 The Quantum Theory of Light) and has identical form to the classical $g^{(1)}$ from eq 3.4.14.
My question is now: say I calculate classical $g^{(1)}$ crosscorrelation between the complex amplitudes at two output port planes of an optical switch generated from identical inputs (a gaussian beam) in ray-tracing software. Can I use this number as my quantum g1/visibility for the case where two identical photons have gone through the same pair of switch input ports and leave through the same pair of switch output ports? If yes, is there a paper or textbook where I can see a clear derivation of this fact? If not, then why not?
Thank you.

The second expression does not look right. When one detects two photons one needs to number operators. A single ladder operator does not represent a photon detection.

Thank you for your comment. Please look at the paper where I have taken/modified that expression from to ensure I/they have not made a mistake. Perhaps also my expression above is irrelevant as we can see $g^{(1)}$ directly expressed purely in terms of the photon waveforms in eq 64/67 of the Trivedi 2019 paper.

If the transformation implemented by the switch is a linear-optical transformation, then you can use classical light to characterize the device's effect on quantum states of light. Is that along the lines of what are asking?

@fulis The effect of the switch on light, in this case a Gaussian beam, is simulated using Code V ray-tracing software. The switch is effectively composed of fibre and a series of lenses (and actuators that move the fibre). The light is affected by, for example, absorption loss, coupling loss, clipping and general broadening and unbroadaning caused by propagation through free space. If that and those effects count as linear-optical transformations, then yes that is what I'm asking. (cont)

(cont) But more simplistically, in general, can the classical g1 crosscorrelation between complex amplitudes of two output light beams generated using classical ray-tracing software be taken as the quantum g1 between two single photons. E.g if I calculate, as above, my classical g1 to be 0.99. Then can I assume my quantum g1 would be 0.99? Thank you.

All the expressions in Eqs (64) to (67) are about $g^{(2)}$ and not $g^{(1)}$. That means that they involve two detections as required for Hong-Ou-Mandel. Perhaps you are confusing them with Eqs (59) and (60) where the authors mention $g^{(1)}$.

The Hong-Ou-Mandel effect is a quantum interference effect that cannot be duplicated in classical theory.

Regarding eqs 64-67. Take equation 64 and set $g^2$ to 1, this is because we assume we have single photons. Then 64 reads $g^{(2)}{HOM}[0] = 1 - v$. Equate our equation 64 to equation 66 with their $P_i$s (different meaning from my P above) being 1. This gives us $v=abs(\iint \phi{a}^{}(t)\phi_b(t') dtdt')$. Using eq 60 we then get $g^1 = v=abs(\iint \phi_{a}^{}(t)\phi_b(t') dtdt')$

Thank you again for your comments. I should add that I am aware I might be making a severe category error here, I just want to nail down where it is. So, ignoring entirely my derivations in my question and the paper, there are eqs 3.4.14 and eq 4.12.4 in Loudon 2000 The Quantum Theory of Light. Both are g^1 and have the same structure. One is for the classical electric field amplitudes one is for the quantum electric field operators. Is it a complete category error to equate them?

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qute.201900007 An interesting read that might be in the right direction
